# QuickSight not showing DataSource created with API

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I've recently started looking into creating dashboards and analysis with the Quicksight API.  I tried creating a datasource using the AWS SDK, the response was successful and I was also able to double-check this by calling a describe on the datasourceId. However, when I logged in to quicksight GUI it doesn't show in the list of datasources, can someone explain why this is happening.

Comment: Not sure, I’m also new to QS. But could it be that your QS user doesn’t have the permission to use this data source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's a permission issue.

This was resolved if I add permissions when creating data sets and data sources.

```js
const input: CreateDataSourceCommandInput = {
    ...
    Permissions: [
      {
        Actions: [
          'quicksight:DescribeDataSource',
          'quicksight:DescribeDataSourcePermissions',
          'quicksight:PassDataSource',
        ],
        Principal: 'USER_ARN',
      },
    ],
    ...
  }
```

To retrieve `USER_ARN`, refer to this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/discovering-hot-topics-using-machine-learning/quicksight-principal-arn.html

API document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDataSource.html#QS-CreateDataSource-request-Permissions

Answer (score 0):

Go to Quicksight and click "New Dataset" button.
inside tab you can check your database ,if not visible logout from cloud and relogin.